# My app is not showing in the google play store after 18 hrs

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Good evening.I have a big issue.I uploaded my app titled "Christmas 15 HD" eighteen hours ago to the play store.Till now as I write this my app is not showing in the play store market.I don't know why but I am able to view it on the web through the link given on the developer console https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16 .

My app shows Published and the status is "in Prod" ..Please what did I do wrong.Any Hint or solution is welcome.Am a lot worried because my app is a seasonal app and all my marketing efforts are behind schedule.Kindly help thanks

Here's my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider937706349616127"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.ChristmasGroundhog"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_christmas_groundhog"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.Arrowman"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_arrowman"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.GenerationofSantas"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_generationof_santas" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.Stories"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_stories"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.iloveyoumore"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_iloveyoumore"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.theredmermaid"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_theredmermaid"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.theFlare"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_the_flare"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.thedarkMagissa"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_thedark_magissa"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.theSpectre"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_the_spectre"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.theFllyingSanta"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_the_fllying_santa"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.thedwarfSanta"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_thedwarf_santa"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.theoldmanwhofinallysmiled"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_theoldmanwhofinallysmiled"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.stonesoup"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_stonesoup"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.thereluctantsanta"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_thereluctantsanta"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.afathersgiftoftime"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_afathersgiftoftime"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.adonkeystale"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_adonkeystale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.theSantaFlashMob"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_the_santa_flash_mob"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.perfectday"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_perfectday"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.fcs.momohozaveshe.christmas16.thesantaclaus"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_thesantaclaus"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name ="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges ="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

</application>
```

Comment: I can see it and download it. So where's the issue?

Comment: you mean you are not able to see the app in mobile version of play store right ? If yes, check if you have enabled the app to be viewed in all countries, better wait

Comment: @noev....Sorry please what phone are you using and what country..

Comment: @AzeezHammedOlayinka I'm using a galaxy S6 in Denmark.

Comment: Yes the app is distributed to all countries @penta. From my little findings I heard it doesn't take more than four-six hours

Comment: Okay Thank you @noev Really appreciate your effort..Are you able to completely download it..

Comment: @AzeezHammedOlayinka Alright I tested the download too, it's working.

Comment: Thank you @noev ..I guess I just have to wait....Thanks once again

Comment: i also can see ur app so there shouldnt be any problem, btw it is better to upload ur manifest if u can

Comment: Hey @Spentas Thank you..Have updated my question.It now includes my manifest.Kindly check and if there is anything wrong.Its my first app so maybe am not doing something right

Comment: seems ok, did u targeted all countries? u can also use this link to find out ur problem https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=en

Comment: Yes all countries.Thank you Spentas for your efforts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

most probably you have done wrong filtering for your application. Google Play uses the filter restrictions to determine whether to show your application to a user who is browsing or searching for applications from the Google Play app.
for example if you set android:normalScreens="false", only users with tablet can see your app in google play. you also need to consider the visibility of your app in different regions. 
refer to this link for more information 
http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Comment: Also take in account different type of sensors, which may not be present on all devices.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I am not using any Filters in my application.The minimum required sdk is 4.0.3 and it shows that my app can be used on 9153 devices.